# Updating JavaScript Quiz Score Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am creating a quiz with JavaScript and jQuery. It is almost to where I want it to be, but the score counter doesn't seem to work. I believe it may be a problem with the order in which the code in executed. I simply want to add one to the 'score' variable when the 'value' vaiable (checks which radio button is checked) equals the current question object's answer value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = -1;
    var qNum = 0;
    var score = 0;
    $(".radbut").hide();
    $("br").hide();

//display value upon radio button checked change - for debugging purposes
$('.radbut').change(function() {
    var value = ($('input[name="Q"]:checked').val());
    alert(value);
});     

    $("#next").click(function(){
        var value = ($('input[name="Q"]:checked').val()); //checks which radio button is checked and sets it to value
        i += 1;
        qNum += 1;
        $(".radbut").show();
        $("br").show();

        //display questions and variables
        $("#questionLoc").text(allQuestions[i].question);
        $("#R1").text(allQuestions[i].choices[0]);
        $("#R2").text(allQuestions[i].choices[1]);
        $("#R3").text(allQuestions[i].choices[2]);
        $("#R4").text(allQuestions[i].choices[3]);
        $("#qNum").text(qNum);
        $("#score").text(score);
        $("#value").text(value);
        $("#quesVal").text(allQuestions[i].answer);

        //add +1 to score if choice matches answer
        if (value == allQuestions[i].answer) {
            score++;
            };
        });
});

var allQuestions = [];

function question(question, choices, answer) {
                this.question = question;
                this.choices = choices;
                this.answer = answer;
};

var question1 = new question("Who is Sansa\'s mother?", ["Cercei", "Marjorie", "Catelin", "Lysa"], 3);
var question2 = new question("Where are the Starks from?", ["Winterfell", "King's Landing", "Valyria", "Dorne"], 1);
var question3 = new question("Who is the biggest asshole in this group?", ["Eddard", "Khaleesi", "Bran", "Geoffrey"], 4);
var endSent = new question("End");

allQuestions.push(question1, question2, question3, endSent);
```

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Game of Thrones Trivia Quiz</title>
</head>
```

```
</header>

<h3>"Please choose the correct answer for the question given. Do so promptly - winter is coming.</h3>

<p id="questionLoc">Click "Next" to begin</p>

    <input type="radio" name="Q" value= 1 class="radbut" /><span id="R1"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Q" value= 2 class="radbut" /><span id="R2"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Q" value= 3 class="radbut" /><span id="R3"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Q" value= 4 class="radbut" /><span id="R4"></span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="next">Next</div>
    <p id="qNum"></p><span>Question</span>
    <p id="score"></p><span>score</span>
    <p id="value"></p><span>value</span>
    <p id="quesVal"></p><span>quesval</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does indeed have to do with the order of your code. When you were checking for the correct answer, you had already incremented the `i` value, so you checked against the current/new question instead of the previous one.

I also added hiding the answers and some other checks to prevent JS errors when arriving at the last question that has now answer choices. (By the way, design-wise I would not put the "End" text in as a question of its own... A question should be a question with answer choices, period.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = -1;
    var qNum = 0;
    var score = 0;
    var toggleElements = $(".radbut, br, #next, #R1, #R2, #R3, #R4");
    $(".radbut").hide();
    $("br").hide();

    $("#next").click(function(){
        var value = ($('input[name="Q"]:checked').prop('checked', false).val()); //checks which radio button is checked and sets it to value
    if (i >= 0) {
          //add +1 to score if choice matches answer
          if (value == allQuestions[i].answer) {
              score++;
              };
        }
        
        i += 1;
        qNum += 1;
        
        toggleElements[allQuestions[i].choices ? 'show' : 'hide']();

        //display questions and variables
        $("#questionLoc").text(allQuestions[i].question);
        
        if (allQuestions[i].choices) {
          $("#R1").text(allQuestions[i].choices[0]);
          $("#R2").text(allQuestions[i].choices[1]);
          $("#R3").text(allQuestions[i].choices[2]);
          $("#R4").text(allQuestions[i].choices[3]);
        }
        
        $("#qNum").text(qNum);       
        $("#score").text(score);
        $("#value").text(value);
        $("#quesVal").text(allQuestions[i].answer);
    });
});

var allQuestions = [];

function question(question, choices, answer) {
                this.question = question;
                this.choices = choices;
                this.answer = answer;
};

var question1 = new question("Who is Sansa\'s mother?", ["Cercei", "Marjorie", "Catelin", "Lysa"], 3);
var question2 = new question("Where are the Starks from?", ["Winterfell", "King's Landing", "Valyria", "Dorne"], 1);
var question3 = new question("Who is the biggest asshole in this group?", ["Eddard", "Khaleesi", "Bran", "Geoffrey"], 4);
var endSent = new question("End");

allQuestions.push(question1, question2, question3, endSent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="questionLoc">Click "Next" to begin</p>

    <input type="radio" name="Q" value= 1 class="radbut" /><span id="R1"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Q" value= 2 class="radbut" /><span id="R2"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Q" value= 3 class="radbut" /><span id="R3"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Q" value= 4 class="radbut" /><span id="R4"></span>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="next">Next</div>
    <p id="qNum"></p><span>Question</span>
    <p id="score"></p><span>score</span>
    <p id="value"></p><span>value</span>
    <p id="quesVal"></p><span>quesval</span>
```

Comment: You might also want to uncheck the current answer when proceeding to the next question, which I have now also edited into my answer.

Comment: Updated again to add some optimizations. I guess this is only a prototype for demonstration, but if not, you should save jQuery collections (= elements selected via jQuery) into variables instead of having to re-collect them on every call of the click handler functions for example.

Answer (score -2):

I am not 100% sure, and am only trying to give my best answer, but would creating the 'score' variable as a constant possibly help? Instead of declaring it inside of in '$(document).ready(function()', put it outside?

Comment: As all code accessing the score variable is insode the ready handler, that cannot be the problem, so why pollute global scope?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm relatively new to coding, and am just trying to help out. If you could explain why my proposed answer is incorrect, I would appreciate it; I am trying to learn.

Comment: It would be better to give an answer if you're sure what you're suggesting. ;-) As I explained, the variable is also in the correct scope. It is bad practice to pollute the global scope with varibles unless neccessary.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to contribute with my best knowledge. Thank you for explaining though, I understand. It's good to learn new things!